# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 dual boot issues

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have Windows 7 installed in sda1 and Ubuntu 10.04 installed in sda5 as root and sda6 as home.

Since installing Windows after Ubuntu, I am unable to boot into Ubuntu. I booted via a live CD and followed the instructions here:

> http://www.ohbuntu.blogspot.com/2009/11/repair-grub2-after-install-windows-7.html

I am having two issues:

1. I ran `grub-install` which said:

   ```
   Installation finished. No error reported.
   ```

   However when I rebooted, I could not see the GRUB menu screen on startup.
2. I created an menu entry for Windows 7 both by editing `grub.cfg` manually and by editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom files`.

   In both cases, when I try to run `update-grub`, I get the below error:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# update-grub
   /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
   ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) / [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099) already?  I'm sure you can find an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've had some challenges with Windows & Ubuntu booting as late. I've found that rather than directly using grub to manage it all, I'm having better success if I install "[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)" which is a boot manager that uses BCD (the boot system now used by Windows).

It's actually quite slick and I suggest people at least give it a chance. Personally I prefer the more GNU approach, but, EasyBCD gets the job done and I don't care THAT much.. ;)

Another option I often suggest is [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub-disk/) - but that's just to help you boot an otherwise unbootable environment.